# Flot - How to make barchart have consistent width even if there is only 1 data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flot

How to keep the bar width consistent  when there is more than one bar?
For example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3Vqh/242/):

```
var testing = $.plot($("#example-section15 #flotcontainer"), dataset, options);    
testing.getOptions().series.barWidth = 5;
testing.draw();
```

When there is only one data point the bar width become very big although I already try to set the `barWidth` and redraw it again but it does not work.

Here is the result when ther is only one data point:

[image]

Comment: Set min and max options for the x-axis.

Comment: @Raidri I can use max and min options, but the data stay in its place, the expected result is bar data will show on the center of the chart if only one data and if more than one data, it should be on the center of the chart.
If I use max and min options, the data stay in its position (for example data 1, so it will show in data 1, and the other is empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bar width is always consistent in term of x-axis units. So you have to make sure, the total width of the chart in x-axis units is also fixed. You can do this by setting the `min` and `max` options for the x-axis so that the difference is always the same.

If for example you have a maximum of 5 bars you could that the total width to 6 units. To always center the existing bars in the chart set the `min` and `max` options so that the center of the bars is at the center of the chart:

- One bar (positon 1): Set `min: -2, max: 4`
- Two bars (center at 1.5): Set `min: -1.5, max: 4.5` ([fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/t3Vqh/243/))
- ...
- Five bars (center at 3): Set `min: 0, max: 6`

Comment: This is what i really need. Hahah. So I just need to set the max and min options depend on how many Data i need to show. Thanks a lot